# Nested Form Doesn't Save Nested Model Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a form that creates a game and game_players at the same time.
The problem I am having is that when I submit the form, the game is created, but the game_players are not.

I've looked around, but haven't found any helpful answers.

Game Model

```rb
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :game_players, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_players

  attr_accessible :league_id, :game_date

  validate :league_id,  :presence => true
end
```

Game_Player Model

```rb
class GamePlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :users

  validate :game_id,  :presence => true
  validate :user_id,  :presence => true
end
```

Game Controller

```rb
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = "New Game"
    @game = Game.new
    3.times { @game.game_players.build }
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(:league_id => cookies[:league_id])
    if @game.save
      flash[:success] = "Succesfully Created Game"
      redirect_to League.find_by_id(cookies[:league_id])
    else
      @title = "New Game"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Form

```rb
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :game_players do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <%= builder.label :user_id, "User" %><br />
      <%= builder.text_field :user_id %><br />
</p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely you need to pass `:game_players_attributes` to `attr_accessible` since .new respect mass-assignment security